Inner Join using Like Operator in Big Query
I have a list of c.11k strings that I need to partially match to string IDs within a BigQ table.
T1 is the original BQ table and T2 is a table with a column of the 11,000 strings
At the minute I have following query
Select T1.ID,T2.ID from T1

JOIN T2 on T1.ID LIKE '%' || T2.ID || '%' 

I have tested this on a subset of the data and it works as expected producing



T1
T2




15688463
56884



But I am aware that when I scale this to the full population it will be a very expensive query.
Is there a way that I can optimise this query or indeed another method for getting the result (other than splitting the 11,000 into subsets),
Thanks in advance

If you want all the partial matches  you have no choice but test all the pairs.

For large tables, take a look in Search Index feature.

My experience is that BigQuery is superb for massive queries.  11,000 records doesn't feel like a lot.  Some BigQuery tables have billions of rows.  Do you reall mean to look for the T1.ID contained "within" the T2.ID as opposed to a direct equality match?
